# Unable to upgrade tensorflow to 1.3.0

Tags: linux, tensorflow

My current tensorflow version is 1.2.1, and I want to upgrade it to a new version 1.3.0. I download the whl file from website and type the command in the terminal:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade tensorflow_gpu-1.3.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

but it couldn't work. It gives me the following message:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: mock>=2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow-gpu==1.3.0)
Downloading/unpacking tensorflow>=1.2.0 (from tensorflow-tensorboard<0.2.0,>=0.1.0->tensorflow-gpu==1.3.0)
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement tensorflow>=1.2.0 (from tensorflow-tensorboard<0.2.0,>=0.1.0->tensorflow-gpu==1.3.0)
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for tensorflow>=1.2.0 (from tensorflow-tensorboard<0.2.0,>=0.1.0->tensorflow-gpu==1.3.0)
Storing debug log for failure in /home/zxf/.pip/pip.log
```

Anyone knows what's wrong with?

Comment: I got `Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement tensorflow>=1.2.0 (from tensorflow-tensorboard>=0.1.0,<0.2.0->tensorflow-gpu==1.3.0)`

Comment: Can you check upgrading tensorflow for CPU and the do the upgrade for GPU? I faced a similar issue and this worked for me.

Comment: @ Chinni You mean upgrading tensorflow for CPU before for GPU ? Is there any connections between CPU and GPU tensorflow version in installation? Or is there any official docs to address this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, upgrading for CPU before and then for GPU. I just tried it and it worked. I didn't refer to any docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I face the same problem. Just try upgrade CPU version which will upgrade all needed libraries. Then upgrade GPU version, everything works fine.